# What is this study on the efficacy of tenocyte therapy?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tendinosis&oldid=778129911#Tendon_bioengineering:

> The future of non-surgical care for tendinosis is likely bioengineering. Ligament reconstruction is possible using mesenchymal stem cells and a silk scaffold.[37] These same stem cells were capable of seeding repair of damaged animal tendons.[38] Autologous tenocyte implantation is currently being tested for tendinosis. There is a large randomized, double-blind, placebo controlled trial being conducted in the Netherlands to test the safety and efficacy of tenocyte therapy. Results from the trial are expected by April 2013.

Which study are they talking about in the last sentence, and what was the outcome of the study?

Comment: Possibly [this one](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0363546513504285)? Lead is a doctor at a Nedlands hospital.

Comment: @JohnP Nedlands is a suburb of Perth, Australia; Carey likely found the one referred to.

Comment: @BryanKrause Oops! Good catch. I read Nederlands but you're right that it's Nedlands in Australia.

Comment: @BryanKrause - I mistyped it as Nederlands. It is Nedlands, and is the same study.

Comment: @JohnP The Australian non-randomized, non-controlled study in Nedlands and the Netherlands RCT are separate. The wikipedia article is probably referencing the latter, not the former.

Comment: @BryanKrause - NM. I'm having a bad morning. :p

Comment: No worries, hope the rest of your day is an improvement. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to be sure from such scant information, but it would quite possibly be this one:

**[Autologous Tenocyte Implantation in Patients With Chronic Achilles Tendinopathy (ATI)](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT01343836?cond=tenocyte&rank=1)**

Comment: Also helpful perhaps: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=NCT01343836